# Php function substr blanks the whole string if there's a capital letter with an accent mark

Tags: php, laravel

TLDR: strlen('Ángel Gallardo Perez',0,15) returns blank. But 'Angél Gállardo Pérez' has no problems. How to use strlen with a capital marked accent letter?

Longer:

Hello. Currently I'm having problem showing a list of clients. Due to the language being spanish I've got to show some letters with a marked accent. Non-capital letters are not a problem (áéíóú) but capital accentuated letters are (ÁÉÍÓÚ)

Currently am showing the name like this:

```
strlen($tempnombre) > 15 ? substr($tempnombre,0,15)."..." : $tempnombre;
```

The idea being that if you've got a short name, I show it as it is. But if its long, I shorten it and add the "..."

When I've got a name like Ángel, strlen returns nothing. I'm sure its that function and that function alone since everything else just returns the name OK. If I just return the name as is, then it shows perfectly.

I've tried a couple of things already:

```
    $tempnombre = $this->nombre;
    mb_convert_case(utf8_encode($tempnombre), MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
    //NAME HERE IS STILL WORKING OK, dd($tempnombre) -> returns OK
    return strlen($tempnombre) > 15 ? substr($tempnombre,0,15)."..." : $tempnombre;
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it after posting the question... If anyone needs it the proper way is as follows:

```
strlen($this->nombre) > 15 ? mb_substr($this->nombre,0,15,'UTF-8')."..." : $this->nombre;
```

Use mb_substr instead of substr.

Comment: Also use `mb_strlen` for an actual character count instead of counting bytes in the string